# Where the heck is the Android app's lib folder?

Tags: java, android, jar

I've been trying to find the so-called ***lib*** folder, to install some 3rd-party tools ([this](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)) there. They tell you to: "place it (*downloaded jar file*) in your Android app’s libs/ folder". But, in Eclipse, I could not find the lib folder even after expanding all of the directories shown in the navigator area. Will someone tell me where this lib folder is? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use Eclipse do the following:

1. Right-click your project and hit 'Project Properties'.
2. Choose 'Java Build Path'.
3. Choose the 'Libraries' tab.
4. Hit 'Add External JARs...'.
5. Navigate to your desired .jar-file and hit 'Open'.
6. Click 'OK'.

Then you should be able to reference your external library.

Comment: Great solution thanks Kasper! This immediately solved my problem of not being able to reference the external library. Now I can use the library just fine, and I did not even need to add a lib folder.

Answer (score 9):

You have to create it if it's not already there. It should be in the top level of your project folder, at the same level as the `src` and `res` folders.

Answer (score 2):

Your lib folder is indeed used for storing external libraries.

This is commonly used to hold external .jars for external libraries, similar to how a .dll works.

You need to place the files in this folder yourself, then add them to the project as an existing archive to use them.

Let me know if this is unclear or you have any more questions!

EDIT:

You need to make sure you're putting this in your imports:

```
import myLib.fullyQualifiedClassName.*;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a bit stuck as to how to get my app to actually recognize this folder though...Could you take me a bit farther? I added the lib folder and copied in the .jar. I also added 'import com.loopj.android.http.*;' as instructed here: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ But my app still is not recognizing the library.

Comment: Are you properly importing the libraries?  check my answer above.

Comment: Hey Pheonixblade9. Surprisingly it (import com.loopj.android.http) worked just fine when I added the library in the manner proposed by Kasper Moerch. I chose his answer since it immediately solved my problem, but thank you (and everyone else) very much for your time in responding too.